# v-show not working as expected on IE browser

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, vue-component

Created a div component modal that will show when you browse on IE browser. Used v-show to show the modal and change the value when clicking the icon to close the modal.

What is expected?
It will close the modal because of change value in v-show

What is actually happening?
Nothing happens even the value is changing to false

```
<div class="dashboard-modal" v-show="isModalSearchShow">
  <div class="dashboard-modal__modal-mask">
    <div class="dashboard-modal__modal-wrapper">
      <div class="dashboard-modal__modal-container">
        <div class="dashboard-modal__close-container">
          <a class="acc-icon g1es-icon-close" @click="isModalSearchShow = false"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-modal__title">
          <span>Incompatible Browser</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-modal__description">
          <span>Works best with Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. Please switch to either of these browsers to fully utilize the portal.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-modal__CTA-container">
          <a class="btn btn--blue dashboard-modal__CTARefreshList" @click="loadUrl">Got it</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version that you're using? Does it work as expected on other browsers?

Comment: on other browser it is closing. I am using 2.5.17

Comment: which is the version of IE?

Comment: i am using IE 11

Comment: *how to use VueJS with IE11* should be what you're looking for, you can google about that. In short, IE11 doesn't support ES6 & also Vuejs, you will need a polyfill in order to make it work

Comment: how sad but thank you for answering

Comment: hi @NguyenYou we already have this
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.7.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",

Comment: I suggest you to try to check this example. It is working fine with IE 11 browser. https://jsfiddle.net/deepak10/6gsn1pv4/2/ If it works for you then you can compare it with your project and try to solve the issue. if possible for you then you can also try to share your sample with JSfiddle which we can test with IE 11.